# What does the result of a fitted cox ph model tell me?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I am currently experimenting with [survival analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis) in R. One important Model is the [Cox Proportional Hazard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model). Using the default [lung](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/lung.html) data the R enviroment provides, I would like to play with the model, using the [mlr-package](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/index.html).

My code:

```
data("lung") # get data
lung = na.omit(lung) # remove rows with missing values
lung$status = (lung$status == 2) # convert to logical
n = nrow(lung)
lung.train = sample(n, size = 0.8*n) 
lung.test = setdiff(1:n, train.set)

# cox proportional hazard
coxph.lrn = makeLearner("surv.coxph") 
coxph.tsk = makeSurvTask(data = lung, target = c("time", "status"))
coxph.mod = train(coxph.lrn, coxph.tsk, subset = lung.test) 
coxph.tsk.pred = predict(coxph.mod, task = coxph.tsk, subset = lung.test)
```

The output of `coxph.tsk.pred` will be the following:

```
Prediction: 35 observations
predict.type: response
threshold: 
time: 0.00
   id truth.time truth.event   response
4   2        210        TRUE  1.1528966
21 13        301        TRUE  0.1532789
30 20         12        TRUE  1.9269353
31 21        473        TRUE -0.3327164
35 24         53        TRUE  2.0432497
41 29        460        TRUE  0.3784922
... (#rows: 35, #cols: 4)
```

**Question 1:** What does `response` tell me?

Assumption: exp(response) is the risk ratio between an individual and the average individual. Is this correct?

**Question 2:** I can use the [concordance index](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pec/versions/2018.04.18/topics/cindex) to measure the performance of models predictions, using

```
performance(coxph.tsk.pred, measures = cindex)
# output: 0.79
```

What does the 0.79 tell me?

Assumption: Cindex compares, if two individuals are concordant and outputs 1, if the are. In this case in my understanding cindex should compare the predicted risk of patients and have a look, if a patient with higher risk dies earlier than one with lower risk. This model seems to predict that correctly in ~80% of the cases. Is my assumption correct?